# Does IsDate function in SQL Server treat 201301 as YYYYMM or YYMMDD?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

#### Someone reported this bug on Microsoft Connect:

I came across the following bug report at Microsoft Connection website. The user reported that [*`IsDate (Transact-SQL)`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function was validating periods of the format *`YYYYMM`* for periods involving *2012* but stopped working since the beginning of *2013*.

[***ISDate() returns different results beginning in 2013***](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779223/isdate-returns-different-results-beginning-in-2013)

User has reported that the following as the input data. I have listed what user is expecting and the output from SQL Server.

```
SELECT  ISDATE(201201)      AS CheckDate1   --Expected: 1; Actual: 1
    ,   ISDATE(201301)      AS CheckDate2   --Expected: 1; Actual: 0
    ,   ISDATE(201401)      AS CheckDate3   --Expected: 1; Actual: 0
    ,   ISDATE(20130101)    AS CheckDate4   --Expected: 1; Actual: 1
```

#### Read the MSDN documentation:

I read the documentation on MSDN website about [*`ISDATE (Transact-SQL)`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). The documentation states the below definition but couldn't find any examples that would verify *`YYYYMM`* is being validated by the function.

```
Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; 
otherwise, 0.
```

On the definition about data type [*datetime (Transact-SQL)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), I could not find anything that would suggest **`YYYYMM`** is a valid date format. The value that the user specified is not of [*datetime2*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) format either.

I wrote the below script to find out what is going on.

#### Query attempt to find out what is going on:

```
DECLARE @StartAt    INT;
DECLARE @EndAt      INT;

SET @StartAt    = 200000;
SET @EndAt      = 201312;

;WITH Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT @StartAt AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM Numbers WHERE n < @EndAt
)
SELECT  n           AS Number
    ,   ISDATE(n)   AS IsValidDate 
FROM    Numbers 
WHERE   ISDATE(n) <> 0
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

#### Above query results:

The above query returned *366* rows for each day in the year *2012*. Here is a snapshot of the data between February and March. The value 200229 is considered valid by IsDate but not 200230, which makes me think that IsDate is treating these values of the format **`YYMMDD`** and **not** as *`YYYYMM`* as the user was expecting it.

```
Number  IsValidDate
------  -----------
200227        1
200228        1
200229        1
200301        1
200302        1
200303        1
```

#### Questions:

- Am I correct that *IsDate* is treating the values mentioned above as **`YYMMDD`** and not as **`YYYYMM`**?
- If **`YYMMDD`** is indeed the format that the function is trying to evaluate, which century does it represent. Does it represent values of years **`1920`** or **`2020`** or something else? Or does it not matter?
- I replaced the start and end values in the above query with the below mentioned ones. I have also listed the number of valid rows found between those ranges. Why doesn't the years endings with **00** through **09** do not return any rows?

#### Multiple attempts:

```
Start   End     Rows
------  ------  ----
000000  001231     0
010000  011231     0
020000  021231     0
030000  031231     0
040000  041231     0
050000  051231     0
060000  061231     0
070000  071231     0
080000  081231     0
090000  091231     0
100000  101231   365
110000  111231   365
120000  121231   366
...
...
980000  981231   365
990000  991231   365
```

#### SQL Server version that I used to run the above query:

I ran the above query on [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012) version. I have tagged this question under [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) because the user reported this issue under that version on *Microsoft Connect* website.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2316.0 (X64) 
Apr  6 2012 03:20:55 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> 
(Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: isdate doesn't just look at month and year, it also looks at day, basically it checks if what you passed in can be converted to a date, these people were just lucky they didn't run this in 1999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) is interpreting a six character string as `yymmdd`.
2. It is dependent on the configured [cutoff Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191004.aspx). Default is `2049`, so years ending in `< 50`* is `20xx` and years `>= 50` is `19xx`.
3. Your test code is dealing with integers and is implicitly cast to a string when passed as an argument to `isdate` with no leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

All that isdate does is check if the string can be converted to a date

they were just lucky that 12 is a valid month

run this as an example

```
SELECT ISDATE('201201'),ISDATE('201301'),ISDATE('199901')
```

As you can see 1999 also returns 0

And of course you can have fun with stuff like this

```
SELECT ISDATE(CONVERT(DATETIME,0)),ISDATE(CONVERT(DATETIME,''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your results it would seem that eg `201201` or `201301` is interpreted as `YYMMDD`. (And the date with month 13 is then considered invalid.)